# How to use Eloquent fluent syntax to update records after joining?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to use fluent syntax with eloquent to achieve the same results as the below SQL query would achieve.

```
UPDATE t
SET t.completed = t.completed + 1
FROM  [groups] AS g
INNER JOIN [quotas] AS t ON t.qid = g.qid
WHERE g.iid = 12234
```

The `groups` table has a model called `group`. Also, the `quotas` table has a model called `quota`

What is the correct way to join the two model and increment the `quota.completed` property?

Note, each model point to a different database.

Comment: You say they are in different databases, are those databases on the same server instance?

Comment: yes they are on the same server but different databases. I am using two different eloquent connection. Each model has a property called `protected $connection = 'connection name';` to define the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would first need to define the relationship between `groups` and `quotas`:

```
public function quota(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Quotas', 'qid', 'qid');
}
```

Then your Eloquent query would then be:

```
Groups::where('iid', 12234)->with('quota')->first()->quota()->increment('completed');
```

This is assuming that the `where` clause will only return one row. It it returns multiple, you will instead need to loop through the collection that is returned:

```
Groups::where('iid', 12234)->with('quota')->get()->each(function( $item, $key ){
    $item->quota()->increment('completed');
});
```

Alternativly, you can use the QueryBuilder:

```
DB::connection('connForGroups')->table('groups')
    ->join('dbname.quotas', 'groups.qid', '=', 'dbname.quotas.qid')
    ->where('groups.iid', '=', 12234)
    ->increment('dbname.quotas.completed');
```

Comment: using the relation did not work but using the query builder worked.

Comment: @Jaylen please see my update, it will now work correctly using Eloquent